# How to call file browser of ckeditor from plugin?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, fckeditor

I need to call widow of dialog "filebrowser" from ckeditor.
I tried to call the plugin via the command 
`CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.execCommand('filebrowser')` but did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following incantation:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.commands.image.exec();
```

Comment: This works at least in the current up-to-date version when the image plugins is loaded. Some null checks might be appropriate ;).

Comment: No, it showed me window dialog of image. I need call event of "Browse server" button.

Comment: Ok, what do you want to do with it without the image context? Are you trying to get the user to insert an image with default properties? Or to insert an image yourself with default properties? Or what? I'm asking because I'm getting a small hint of an XY problem here to be honest and I don't understand the context.

Comment: I have ckeditor and ckfinder. In ckeditor added to the panel by pressing the button on which I want to get a window for selecting the image files on the server. When window of  ckfinder is closed paste them into the editor. The result is a gallery of pictures.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand that, but it sounds a bit like you might want to do a custom ckedittor plugin for that.  Or do you already have that? Are you trying to bind the ckfinder to open up when clicking a button in your plugin dialog or by clicking a toolbar icon? If you are trying to initiate it completely outside the cke plugin system... why? :D

Comment: Small note - commands should be executed by the `editor.execCommand()` method. By calling `command.exec()` you bypass part of the feature.

Answer (score -1):

Try:
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.commands.image.exec();